# How to transfer delta records from one table to another in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have one `table t1` with attributes

```
emp_joined_date,
emp_name,
emp_number.
```

and I want to transfer this table to another table `t2(having same structure)`.

during 1st attempt I will transfer whole table but later I want to transfer only `delta records` from table `t1 to t2`.

So *how do I insert multiple records from table t1 to t2 in single query(in oracle)*

Comment: Is there any code you have tried?

Comment: no..I have searched on Google for such code but i did not get satisfactory answers or code suggested during my search was not working for scenario i have mentioned

Comment: @Aniket - Please mark the answer which worked for you, so the question can be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
insert into t1
select * from t2
where emp_number not in 
(select t2.emp_number from t2 join t1 on t1.emp_number = t2.emp_number) ;
```

Comment: Thanks friend for your help.. I have tried this query and it worked.. So thanks again...:)

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't mind, you can mark the solution as answered

Answer (score 0):

If you get new records in `t1` and you want to insert only those in `t2`, then use this. It will give you new `emp_number`

```
insert into t2 (emp_joined_date,emp_name,emp_number)
select t1.emp_joined_date,t1.emp_name,t1.emp_number 
from t1 left join t2
on t1.emp_number=t2.emp_number
where t2.emp_number is null
```

If you want to insert records based on time, then use this
Use NVL function so for the first run, it would copy everything.

```
insert into t2 (emp_joined_date,emp_name,emp_number)
select emp_joined_date,emp_name,emp_number from t1 
where emp_joined_date > 
nvl((select max(emp_joined_date) from t1),to_date('1900-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Comment: Thanks friend...:)